# How to disable the animation when loading a page with Framework7 (2.0.10)

Tags: html-framework-7

On the 1.4.0 version, there was a specific class for that purpose "no-animation", as you can see on source code (framework7.js)

```
var animatePages;
if (typeof clickedData.animatePages !== 'undefined') {
    animatePages = clickedData.animatePages;
}
else {
    if (clicked.hasClass('with-animation')) animatePages = true;
    if (clicked.hasClass('no-animation')) animatePages = false;
}
```

But in the last version of Framework7 (2.0.10) there is no more any mention of this class. How to disable animations then?

Answer (score 4):

You can disable while initializing the framework7 in js file.

```
var app = new Framework7({
  view: {
      animate : false,
  }
});
```

This disable's page animation in all pages.

Answer (score 1):

In v2, you have to pass a boolean property (`animate`) to route options.
There is [documentation link](http://framework7.io/docs/routes.html#route-options) for that.

If you want to disable all pages animation, add property in default route :

routes: [
        //routes definitions
        ...,
       {
            path: '(.*)',
            animate: false
       }
    ]

Comment: I saw something like that in source code and already tried this solution, but was not working. I will try again (I finally disabled the animation directly on source code for the moment). Thank you

Comment: Weird... Have you use default routes params (path : '(.*)' ) ?

Answer (score 0):

the info above is accurate, although this only disable page animation transition. let's say when you navigate from page X to Y, it will not show any animation. However to disable any animation, side-bar slide duration, dialog prompt fade-in / fade-out etc...

to remove all animation, this is a two step operation

first declare a new class in your CSS

```
/* Reduce animation duration to a bare minimum. */
/* we've found that there is dialog stuck here and there when put it to 0ms */
.animation-desactivee * {
    -webkit-transition: 10ms !important;
    -moz-transition: 10ms !important;
    -o-transition: 10ms !important;
    -ms-transition: 10ms !important;
    transition: 10ms !important;
}
```

then you must add this class in you app:

```
this.f7animation = environment.animate;
if (!this.f7animation) {
    this.f7App.app.root.addClass("animation-desactivee");
}
```